# Unable to import android.view.View in training app

Tags: android

I'm new to Android Studio and am working with Oreo. I am trying to work through the training app and seem unable to import View.  I tried clicking View per instruction and pressing Alt-Enter but the import statement does not get inserted. I then tried to manually type the statement but this too fails. The entire code follows. Any help will be appreciated. TIA.

```
package com.example.spsar.myfirstapp

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View  // ***** failing statement


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view) {}  // ***** View clicked here

}
```

Comment: Upon reexamination I found my MainActivity file was a .KT file and not a .Java file. I started a new project making sure the Kotlin box was NOT checked. The MainActivity came up as a .Java file and everything is working properly. This does not resolve the Oreo/Kotlin issue I was experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Upon reexamination I found my MainActivity file was a .KT file and not a .Java file. I started a new project making sure the Kotlin box was NOT checked. The MainActivity came up as a .Java file and everything is working properly. This does not resolve the Oreo/Kotlin issue I was experiencing.